# How do I create static WordPress pages that are dynamically pulled from database?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, dynamic, static

I have a bunch of data in a MySQL database indexed by auto-incremented `id` values.

A row would look like this:

```
id | title                           | description                       | story
1  | A good day in the neighborhood. | Mr. Rogers is in the neighborhood | A long text wall here...
```

There is new data added to the database via cron jobs every 6 hours. I would like to generate static pages with this data automatically. Right now I have dynamic pages i.e. www.mysite.com/story?id=1

Really I'd like to have a static page that is accessed at www.mysite.com/title-of-story

I've looked around but can't really find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Austin,
  Your question is a bit vague when you say "a static page."  You're referencing these as "stories" which leads me to believe they are more blog posts than pages.  So are you looking to have a user go to one URL on your WP site that then shows a list of all these stories?  Or are you looking to have a user go to your wordpress site and see a blogroll of your stories from the non WP MySQL tables?

If it's the latter you can consider an Exact Transform and Load script (ETL) that takes data from your MySQL table above and moves it into the wp_posts table.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would classify them I guess. They are news stories which all have a heading, description, and the story itself. I would like each news story to have its own static page. Right now I have a page called story which is passed an id and displays the relevant story data on the story page. So www.mysite.com/story?id=1 and www.mysite.com/story?id=2 are two different dynamically created pages. I would like to have two separate static pages created for them that didn't rely on going to the database every time to look up the information for the story. Does that help clarify?

Comment: Austin - I see, my question now would be where does Wordpress fit into this?  And what is your constraint for not wanting to go to the database?

Comment: WP fits in as I am working for a client with a preexisting WP site. I'd like to not hit the database every time as I would like static pages that search engines can index.

Comment: Austin - WP pages get crawled by search engines all the time, including dynamic posts and pages. Search engine crawlers are quite capable of crawling CMS's. see this link from WP regarding SEO. http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress